# c++ primer chapter 3 iterator conversion error

Tags: c++, iterator

the below code is copied from the c++ primer book. when i put it in my compiler (MS studios express) i get a conversion error saying it cannot go from type string to type int. in the for statement i dereferenced the iterator so i do not understand why i am getting the error. any help?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
vector<string> svec, svec1;
string s1;

while (cin >> s1){ svec.push_back(s1); }

for (auto a1 = svec.begin(); a1 != svec.end() && !isspace(*a1); ++a1){
    *a1 = toupper(*a1);
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a1 != svec.end` should be `a1 != svec.end()`. missing `()`

Comment: i added the missing () and still have the same error.

Comment: @user3089453 Which error exactly? Be precise, post error messages literally in your question. _"error saying it cannot go from type string to type int."_ wishy washy rephrased doesn't count. And why all those `*a1` dereferencing attempts?!?

Comment: It wont work. You are dereferencing `a1` a string vector iterator and passing it to `isspace` which expects an int. Are you sure you dont need another iteration inside this to iterate over the actual strings rather than the vector? The point is to convert your strings to uppercase?

Answer (score 1):

`*a1` is a `string`. You cannot do `isspace(*a1)` because `isspace` expects a character, not a string. Same for `toupper`.

Your loop looks like a Frankenstein stitch-up of a loop to iterate over the vector and with a loop to iterate over each character of a string.

I'm guessing you want to convert all the strings, in which case the code would be:

```
for ( auto str = svec.begin(); str != svec.end(); ++str )
    for (auto a1 = str->begin(); a1 != str->end(); ++a1 )
        *a1 = toupper(*a1);
```

NB. If you're using `auto` it means your compiler has C++11 support, so it would be simpler to use range-based `for` loops.